# OKD 3.10 - Activating full random port allocation in iptables

Tags: openshift, iptables, okd

Is it possible to enable full random port allocation in CentOS 7?

It looks like `--random-fully` is available in iptables 1.6.1 vs 1.4.21 that comes with an OKD install.

Has anyone tried this, successfully?

Comment: This the command? `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eno50 -j SNAT --random-fully`

Answer (score 0):

I had to install iptables 1.6.2 (the version that added random-fully to masquerade) from source.

So far so good.

Install I ran:
yum install gcc libmnl-devel libnftnl-devel bison-devel byacc flex flex-devel libnetfilter_conntrack-devel

> ./configure
>
> make
>
> make install
>
> iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eno50 -j MASQUERADE --random-fully